# Generate keystore with same user and password

Tags: android, keystore, signing

I lost my keystore file to sign my android app on google play. I have the user, alias and password that i used. Is is possible to generate a new keystore using the same credentials so i can update the app? Thanks!

Comment: you need to republish a new app with new package name..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suffered from the same...Unfortunately, there is no solution to it because it does not rely on its *user/password*.

It relies on **MD5** or **SHA1** signature which is **auto regenerate** [**randomly**] when the new file is created.

And while uploading the updated app version if this **signature is not the same**, the Google play store **will not accept** the new app version of that package.

*This time I would suggest you keep a copy of the `.keystore` file at drive, mail, etc....*

And don't try to upload the same application with a different package name because the Google play store will automatically *suspend your application* if it finds any similarity with other and this is totally computerized.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, having the credentials (password) without the `.keystore` file will not help you.

The **password protection** is **only an additional security layer** to encrypt the private key that the `.keystore` file contains.
So, if you can't find your old `.keystore` file, there is nothing you can do.

If you still **have access to the disk** where the `.keystore` file was stored, my suggestion is to immediately try a **disk recovery tool** as it can restore deleted files if they haven't been overwritten by new data.

Answer (score 1):

When Google says:

> "Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish an app to Google Play and then lose the key with which you signed your app, you will not be able to publish any updates to your app, since you must always sign all versions of your app with the same key."

it means you have no way to update your app.